# I try to validate a textbox that it should not allow any string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I am trying to validate a textbox that the user should type only numbers in the textbox. Here is my code

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState(null);
  const handleOnChange = (val) => {
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
      setPhoneNumber(val);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={phoneNumber}
        onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-moon-x6il3?file=/src/App.js:0-513
If we start with the string it is not validating, it is allowing you to type the strings. If we start with numbers, it is working fine.
If I change input type to number, I am facing some issue with character `e`.
How to fix this issue?

Comment: Hey, have you tried changing the initial value of your phone number to be an empty string "" rather than null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the initial value of `phoneNumber` in the `useState` from `null` to empty string and it'll work fine. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-margulis-6ij2o?file=/src/App.js:0-508)

Comment: This isn't a very robust solution. Validating a phone number in this way is going to result in weird behaviour. For example, try entering `123456789`, then notice that there is nothing stopping you entering `e+` between the `7` and `8`, a `.` between `1` and `2`, and a `-` at the start of the number. This is a valid floating point number, but it doesn't look like any phone number I've ever seen. There are [libraries for this sort of thing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-phone-number). I can't see any point in re-inventing this wheel.